# mysqldump generating inconsistent dumps

Tags: mariadb, mysqldump, master-slave-replication, mariadb-10.3

I cannot get mysqldump to generate a dump that will properly restore.  The dump is being generated to setup a new slave, but whenever the slave starts up, it gets foreign key constraint failures.

I'm generating the dump with slave positions and as a single transaction so that the dump is (allegedly) atomic, but when I essentially execute the following:

```
mysqldump \
    -h master \
    --flush-logs --single-transaction --master-data \
    --apply-slave-statements \
    --databases my-db \
    | mysql -h slave
```

I get the following error when I "SHOW SLAVE STATUS":

```
Last_Errno: 1452
Last_Error: Error 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ...
```

All of the tables use the InnoDB engine, and the foreign key is an integer.

Using MariaDB 10.3.

Comment: Originally posted to https://serverfault.com/questions/994334/mysqldump-generating-inconsistent-dumps?noredirect=1, but posting here per suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The `--apply-slave-statements` parameter doesn't make sense here, as it is used when you dump from a slave, not from a master.

And this one most likely causes your problems: `--databases my-db`

My guess is, that you expect, that MySQL/MariaDB only replicates the database that you've dumped and restored on the slave. But without filtering MySQL/MariaDB replicates everything from the master to the slave. To filter you can use the following manual page: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/replication-filters/

If that is not your problem, then the first thing I would check is, if someone has disabled foreign key checking on your master with `select @@global.foreign_key_checks;` If this returns `0` it's bad. Then you can use my stored procedure from [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/254461/7867) to check for data inconsistencies.